# Bot not answering messages in microsoft teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm following this Microsoft-teams [tutorial](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node) for a simple bot. I'm running it using VScode in local mode.
It's working in bot emulator. Here is a screenshot of that.
[image]

But It's not working when sideloaded as an app for Microsoft teams. I'm able to send the messages but the bot is not replying back.
[image]

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Any error logged in dev.botframework.com ?

Comment: Microsoft has migrated the dev.botframework to azure bot service. Can you tell me how to get the logs from azure bot service?

Comment: Which all channels are added for this bot? Could you please try adding Skype channel once and see if bot responds to your query in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: sorry for the logs @ashwinids, as I only have bots created with Bot SDK I don't have migrated them yet (it is not possible currently for those bots)

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT This bot uses a ms-teams lib, so  I have added only Teams channel other than web chat. While testing with azure online bot test it works only in web chat channel.

Comment: @ashwinids - could you please share your bot id so that we could check the logs?

Comment: Still no luck. I found the outgoing webhooks is working. Try to use that as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a bug in our bot registration code that is causing this. We are currently investigating its root cause.

As a workaround, add the Skype channel and the MS Teams channel to the bot.

Update: This is no longer a requirement. This is fixed.

Comment: Did you mean that addition of Skype channel is necessary for working with MS Teams channel?

Comment: It seems that the problem still exists. With only teams channel the bot wont work. When i add skype channel it works.

Comment: Adding Skype channel is no longer a requirement for Bots to work in Microsoft Teams.You could use [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#bots) to create Bot which adds Microsoft Teams channel for you.