# New bot not answering messages in microsoft teams

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm running a bot with Microsoft Teams and have it setup in Azure.  It's a demo bot from the bot builder code Microsoft released.  I'm pointing it to a local server that has ngrok running.  This works fine when I test via Web Chat in Azure but it doesn't work at all when working with Teams.

The app sideloads properly and the manifest is accepted by teams.  No response appears to be making it to the server.  When I click to show the Bot Channels in Azure some kind of OPTIONS query is being sent to the server and the demo bot throws a 405 error.

The bot id is `f22039b8-5400-4569-a0f2-5bdceb8431f2` but I can't talk to it in 1:1 chat either when I specify this ID.

There are no logs in Azure or teams- I don't see any errors, so I have no idea how to start debugging this.

This is a link to someone with the exact same question:
[Bot not answering messages in microsoft teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863924/bot-not-answering-messages-in-microsoft-teams)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a bug in our bot registration code that is causing this. We are currently investigating its root cause.

As a workaround, add the Skype channel **and** the MS Teams channel to the bot.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it.  What would happen if I added a Skype channel?  Would that fix the issue for both teams?  I left it going overnight and oddly enough it seems to be have woken up overnight and be working for the moment.

Comment: The only thing that will happen is that you can also use your bot on Skype.

I haven't read that the issue has been fixed but it's possible that it has been. And yes, it would fix it in both teams.

Comment: Hi Bill, has the issue been fixed yet?  Everything was working fine and then recently it began happening again.

Comment: Is the problem still happening?

Comment: A day or two after I posted this, it flipped on and started working again.  Thanks for following up Bill.